# changing an element's className doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, mobx

I want to change the color of an element by switching className, and the className is not changing.

I am currently using nextJS and mobX.

here is the example code:

Example.tsx

```
<div 
  className = {store.isChosen ? 'isChosen' : 'isNotChosen'}
  onClick={()=>{
    store.isChosen = !store.isChosen;
  }}
>ELEMENT</div>

// this doesn't work either
<div 
  className = {store.isChosen ? `{styles.isChosen}` : {styles.isNotChosen}`}
  onClick={()=>{
    store.isChosen = !store.isChosen;
  }}
>ELEMENT</div>
```

ExampleStore.ts

```
@observable
isChosen:boolean = false;
```

Example.module.scss

```
.isChosen{
  background-color: red;
}

.isNotChosen{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Can we have a look at the `ExampleStore.ts` file to see how `isChosen` get updated?

Comment: I would try some debugging first, if you haven't already done it. Manually setting one class or the other produces the expected result? (This way you're sure the problem is not in your CSS). Is the variable `store.isChosen` correctly defined and changing properly?

Comment: @RiadhAdrani I've updated the post. simply change the value by putting ! 
should I set a setter and update the value with it?

Comment: @RiadhAdrani oh, setter made it work. I don't know why though. because 
element like 
{store. isVisible && <div/>} worked

Comment: @heyman_71 I put css just in case, but yes the problem is class not changing. but Riadh gave me a hint and I fixed it

Comment: @RiadhAdrani maybe you can put an answer with why it only works with a setter please. I want to understand how it worked

Comment: Can you reproduce it on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: @Danila Riadh's answer worked. I just don't know why my method didn't work but using a setter did

Comment: That's why i'm asking for repro, your code should work Riadh answer does not really have any helpful info at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **observable** in Mobx is, as its name suggest, observed for any change that can affect it, that's why when you just set the value to something new, it directly reflected. You can even create an observable object and update the values inside like : `myState.stateKey = "new Value"` and it would work too thanks to `Proxy`.

[I invite you to read docs for more infos.](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#observable)

Comment: hmm yeah, but I put observable on isChosen already. when I debugged the boolean value was switching properly. it was just className that wasn't really changing. I was wondering why